# Ошибка в двоичном поиске

Tags: python, бинарный-поиск

Понимаю логику программы, но не понимаю ошибку...

По моим размышлениям я считываю размеры списков, сами списки
и просто передвигаю метку, сравнивая что находится слева и справа
от нее. Многого не знаю. поэтому прошу помощи и как можно более разжеванную

Ввожу:

```
10 10

1 61 126 217 2876 6127 39162 98126 712687 1000000000 

100 6127 1 61 200 -10000 1 217 10000 1000000000
```

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
elem = [input().split(), int]
zap = [input().split(), int]

for i in zap:
    le = 0
    r = len(elem)

    while 1 < r - le:
        m = (le + r) // 2

        if elem[m] < i: # TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'list'
            le = m
        elif elem[m] == zap[i]:
            print("Yes")
            break
        else:
            r = m
```

Comment: Так вы посмотрите, что у вас вообще в переменных elem и zap

Comment: У вас там кортежи из списка и типа.

Comment: @CrazyElf, не совсем вас понял, вижу только 2 списка и не понимаю каких они типов и как сделать их одинакового типа для сравнения

Comment: Ну то есть да, немного не так я написал, у вас в списке сначала ещё один список первым элементом идёт, а потом тип int вторым элементом списка стоит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

Переменные `a` и `b` вы никак не используете, поэтому эта строчка вообще не нужна.

```
elem = [input().split(), int]
zap = [input().split(), int]
```

Тут вы делаете что-то непонятное - создаёте список, внутри которого первым элементом идёт список, полученный разбиением ввода, а второй элемент - тип `int`. Из-за чего у вас потом и выходит ошибка - вы сравниваете **тип** со **списком**. Вместо этого нужно разбивать ввод на элементы и приводить их к типу `int` вот так:

```
elem = list(map(int, input().split()))
zap = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Далее вы итерируетесь по списку и используете **элемент списка** в качестве **индекса** в этом же списке:

```
for i in zap:
    ^^^^^^^^
    ...
    elif elem[m] == zap[i]:
                    ^^^^^^
```

Естественно, это приводит к ошибке - у вас же всего 10 элементов в списке, а не `100` и не `6127`. Сравнивать надо сам элемент списка в этом случае, так же, как это у вас сделано чуть выше для сравнения `<`:

```
    elif elem[m] == i:
```

После этого всё работает. Ввод:

```
1 61 126 217 2876 6127 39162 98126 712687 1000000000
100 6127 1 61 200 -10000 1 217 10000 1000000000
```

Вывод:

```
Yes 6127
Yes 61
Yes 217
Yes 1000000000
```

Comment: Дошло) благодарю